# Can't resolve all parameters for HttpXsrfCookieExtractor: (?, [object Object], [object Object])

Tags: angular, webpack

I`m developing an asp.net core with angular 4.3.6. application.

I tried to install @angular/cli and i got this error:

```
Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
```

I reopened VS and i got:

```
Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module build failed: TypeError: loaderUtils.getOptions is not a function
```

I install 'loader-utils' and i Got:

```
Webpack dev middleware failed because of an error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'. Error was: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
```

I install webpack and i got:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for HttpXsrfCookieExtractor: (?, [object Object], [object Object])
```

And I don't know why I'm getting this and I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the issue by following the solution from the link below

https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/issues/866

Whenyou update your stuff, you need to repack your code...

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js 
webpack
```

if you are unable to do this on the command line, you need to [install the webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/) package globally

```
npm install --global webpack
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also delete the `/wwwroot/dist/` folder to force a full re-compilation upon the first project build.

IMO is the most easy way to force repack.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to update to Angular 4.3.6 and I got the same exception. Looks like it is not possible to upgrade to 4.3.0+

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1242